# Update URL with PHP Variable by AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

Probably a simple solution here, I'm confusing myself.  I've got a `<select>` that populates via an array from a MySQL database of users.  No problem there.  I've also got a script that when a certain user is selected, I can via AJAX the user's user_id.  My problem, is getting that user ID into a variable $assigned_to, to include in a URL.
I'm sorry the coding is so specific.  If requested, I can break it all down into a much more simplified version.
Here's what I've got so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showData(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("showData").innerHTML="";
  return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("showData").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","getdata.php?assign_to="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>

//
//This gets the user_id value from the `<select>` when a user selects it.
//

<?php

//
//Here is the function that displays my users:
//

function userlist()
{               
echo "<select name=\"assigned_to\" onChange=\"showData(this.value)\">";
echo "<option default value=\"\">Assignee</option>";

$mysqli = new mysqli("xxx", "xxx", "xxx", "xxx");
$userlist = "SELECT * FROM users where user_level = 2";
$result = $mysqli->query($userlist);

while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
echo "<option value=\"".$row['user_id']."\">".$row['first_name']." ".$row['last_name']."</option>";
}
echo "</select>&nbsp;";
}
echo "<p>";
echo userlist();

echo "<a id=\"show\" href=\"index.php?page=overview&location=advance&assignee=\"".$assign_to."\">Assign</a></p>";
?>
<!-- The line below **will** display the correct user_id value when selected -->
<div id="showData">User Id Shows Here</div>
```

That last URL variable $assign_to is what I want the value from $row['user_id'] when selected to return.

I understand the ideal method of going about all of this is to just post a form to a php page and using _POST to retrieve all these variables.  Unfortunately in this circumstance I need the variable in the URL.

Thanks as always.

Comment: what you are doing already will send the variable in the url. You can access it with `$_GET["assign_to"]`

Comment: try jquery and ajax, it's a lot easier!

Comment: That doesn't seem to work on the current page.  It will of course work in getdata.php.

Comment: I'm briefly familiar with jquery and AJAX, it's possible to update automatically on select of the `<select>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you are doing here should already do what you want it to do. when the select-box is changed, your showData-function is called with the current selected value of the select-box:

```
<select name=\"assigned_to\" onChange=\"showData(this.value)\">
```

in the showData-function the retrieved argument 'str' contains this value, and you append it to the url:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","getdata.php?assign_to="+str,true);
```

you should see it in the network tab of your preferred debugging tool (firebug, chrome developer tools), or you could just log it to the console/alert it

```
alert("getdata.php?assign_to="+str);
console.log("getdata.php?assign_to="+str);
```

and you will see it works

EDIT:

a redirect to the current page with the param could be done like that (even if i dont understand why you would like to do that...):

```
var current_url = document.location.href;
var separator = current_url.indexOf('?') === -1 ? '?' : '&'; 
document.location.href = current_url + separator + 'assign_to=' + str;
```

EDIT2:

add this function to your scripts:

```
function setLinkAssignee(assignee) {
  var i, newParams = [], link = document.getElementById('show'),
      href = link.getAttribute('href')
      linkArr = href.split('?')
      params = (linkArr[1] || '').split('&');

  for(i=0; i < params.length; i++) {
    if(params[i].indexOf('assignee=') === -1) {
      newParams.push(params[i]);
    }
  }
  link.setAttribute('href', linkArr[0] + '?' + newParams.join('&') + '&assignee='+assignee);
}
```

and call it like this if you dont want the ajax request to be done:

```
<select name=\"assigned_to\" onChange=\"setLinkAssignee(this.value)\">
```

or like this inside your showData:

```
function showData(str) {
  // your stuff here
  setLinkAssignee(str);
```

Comment: Sorry I realized that didn't make sense.  I'm just having trouble understanding how I can get the $_GET['assigned_to'] variable back on the original page that generated the request.

Comment: but you ARE on that page, sorry i really do not understand where your problem is...

Comment: I cannot figure out how to get that variable into this URL: `<a id=\"show\" href=\"index.php?page=overview&location=advance&assignee=\"".$assign_to."\">`

I've tried appending it in an onclick href as well, and for some reason it just returns index.php?page=overview&location=advance&assignee=+str

Comment: see EDIT2, you need to set the link, but parse the url before, remove the current assignee-param, and set the new one